# Is it possible to execute SQL procedure in Delphi 6 BDE TUpdateSQL?

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, bde

Is it possible to write `execute procedure (...with arguments...)` (for Firebird 2.1 database) in Delphi 6 BDE TUpdateSQL.ModifySQL? I have tried, but I am receiving error message `Update failed` even for the simplest SQL procedure. So - are there some restrictions on the statement that can be executed in ModifySQL? I know (and I am using extensively), that it is possible to write `execute procedure` (and more complex statements) in the Delphi IBX TIBDataSet.ModifySQL (or in other similar properties of IBX components). Should I avoid execute procedure in TUpdateSQL or are there tricks that I should take into consideration?

Comment: Avoid the BDE, period.  You are wasting your time not upgrading from it.

Comment: Its not my decision.

Comment: In TUpdateSQL? No. TUpdateSQL expects an `UPDATE` statement (which is why it's called `TUpdateSQL` - the **UpdateSQL** part of  the name should make it clear). `TStoredProcedure` is for executing stored procedures.

Comment: @Ken - get down off your high horse.  TUpdateSQL expects an SQL statement for each of InsertSQL/ModifySQL/DeleteSQL.  Notice that your patronising observation that `TUpdateSQL` requires an `UPDATE` statement and that this is obvious from the name falls down when considering that the `UPDATE` statement is actually expected in the **Modify**SQL property.  So, not a `MODIFY` statement, for example!  Now, `TStoredProc` provides a convenience wrapper around SQL statements that execute stored procedures, but exeucting a stored proc *should* be possible using a SQL statement (e.g. `EXEC PROCNAME()`).

Comment: @Deltics: Don't know what got your panties in an uproar, but you could tone down the offensive tone a bit. I wasn't intending to be condescending at all; I was merely pointing out that the name explains what it expects. You, OTOH, clearly intended to be rude. And IIRC, the ModifySQL is a convenient implementation to allow you to not need a separate TUpdateSQL, but it still expects an UPDATE statement and not a stored procedure.

Comment: You didn't intend to condescend.  I didn't intend to offend.  :shrug:  I merely point out that the use of an UPDATE statement is not directly connected with the component type name (which also has properties for INSERT and DELETE statements).  Perhaps your IIRC is wrong,  After all, "ModifySQL" cannot possibly avoid the "need [for] a separate TUpdateSQL".  ModifySQL *is a property of a TUpdateSQL*.  It might however avoid the need for a separate *TQuery* that you might otherwise use to perform an UPDATE (even though an UPDATE statement is not a query.  Go figure)

Comment: Have you tried to include the stored procedure call within an `UPDATE` statement that, itself, does not update anything?

Comment: @TomR You don't show any code. Provide a [mcve]. As a side note, BDE is fundamentally broken for multi-tier development. The way it manages memory is not scalable. On D6 you're not locked into the BDE for multi-tier development. I strongly advise you to argue for using different Db Providers.

Answer (score 1):

René Hoffmann's idea was right - it is possible to execute procedure from the update statement. E.g. the following statement is accepted in ModifySQL:

```
update target_table set
  id = :id,
  field1 = :field1,
  field2 = (select proc.field2 from additional_actions_procedure(:field2, :param1, :param2) proc) 
where 
  id = :old_id
```

Delphi Unit `DBTables` contains the code that explains why exception is raised:

```
procedure TUpdateSQL.ExecSQL(UpdateKind: TUpdateKind);
begin
  with Query[UpdateKind] do
  begin
    Prepare;
    ExecSQL;
    if RowsAffected <> 1 then DatabaseError(SUpdateFailed);
  end;
end;
```

So affected rows counting happens. But apparently `DBTables` accounting of affected rows differs from the affected rows count in IBExpert. IBExpert counts the real affected rows be they affected by `execute procedure`, `update` statement or other statements. But `DBTables` counts (my guess) only rows of the target table that are updated by `update` statement. More investigation of Delphi code can reveal the more exact explanation.

This comment http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/tupdatesql_many_queries.html suggest editing `DBTables` file.

Comment: I don't know how Firebird counts affected rows (see footnote of my profile for the reason), but it seems there is no `SET NOCOUNT OFF` like option for stored procedures. So, affected row count you might be missing with all database components in Delphi. So long they don't overcome this.